# Nested classes in Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I am new to Gson and I have a json response from an api that is nested. I created nested classes -

```
public class GsOrgIds {
    
    public GsOrgIdsData data;
    public String msg;
    public int retCode;
    
}

public class GsOrgIdsData {
    public int pageNum;
    public int pageSize;
    public int pages;
    public int total;
    public List<GsOrgIdsResult> result;
}

public class GsOrgIdsResult {
    public long createTime;
    public boolean isDefault;
    public String description;
    public String organization;
    public int id;
}
```

and when I try to read it -

```
GsOrgIds value = new Gson().fromJson(response, GsOrgIds.class);
```

I get

```
com.google.gson.JsonIOException: Failed making field 'gsapi.GsOrgIds#data' accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type.
```

Here is a example json  -

```
{
    "data": {
        "result": [
            {
                "id": 49,
                "organization": "Default1",
                "description": "",
                "isDefault": 1,
                "createTime": 1565074728000
            },
            {
                "id": 118,
                "organization": "1",
                "description": "2",
                "isDefault": 0,
                "createTime": 1565158013000
            }
        ],
        "total": 8,
        "pages": 1,
        "pageSize": 30,
        "pageNum": 1
    },
    "msg": "",
    "retCode": 0
}
```

Do I have to write complete deserialization or is there a simpler way to get Gson to see the nested classes? Thanks!

Comment: I got `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a boolean but was NUMBER at line 8 column 31 path $.data.result[0].isDefault`, and it works fine when I change those values to booleans. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: Can you please provide the complete message of the `JsonIOException` or its cause? In particular, does it mention "module" (see [Troubleshooting Guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/Troubleshooting.md#reflection-inaccessible-to-module-gson))? Which Gson version are you using?

Comment: JavaSE-17, Gson 2.10.1

Comment: yes, the cause is - 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field public gsapi.GsOrgIdsData gsapi.GsOrgIds.data accessible: module GSConfig does not "exports gsapi" to module com.google.gson

It will not let me post the entire thing.

Comment: @Marcono1234 Yes, that was it! I just needed to fix my module-info.java file. That was the piece I was missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gson uses reflection to access the fields of your classes. Therefore if your project is using a `module-info.java` file you have to configure it to allow reflective access by Gson.
This can be done by specifying `opens <package-name> to com.google.gson`:

```java
module mymodule {
    requires com.google.gson;

    opens mypackage to com.google.gson;
}
```

Alternatively you can also write `open module mymodule { /* ... */ }` which opens all packages to all modules at runtime.

See the [Gson Troubleshooting Guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/Troubleshooting.md#reflection-inaccessible-to-module-gson) and [Understanding Java 9 Modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) for more information.

And since you mentioned that you have created "nested classes", make sure that these classes are `static`. Otherwise they do not have a default no-args constructor and Gson falls back to using JDK internals for creating instances, which can be error-prone, see also [`GsonBuilder.disableJdkUnsafe()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#disableJdkUnsafe()).